# Пытаюсь удалить модуль pygame через pip на macOS и возникает exception

Tags: python, консоль, pip

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 825, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pygame/' -> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/~ygame'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 105, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 725, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 381, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 272, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 362, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/shutil.py", line 838, in move
    raise PermissionError("Cannot move the non-empty directory "
PermissionError: Cannot move the non-empty directory '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pygame/': Lacking write permission to '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11/pygame/'.```
````

Comment: Там PermissionError, попробуйте через sudo

Comment: @MikhailSibirev да, так работает) спасибо!